# Powershell hashtable.containskey is always returning true

Tags: powershell, containskey

The following code is trying to do one thing. Its trying to find IDs that have been added to an Active Directory group since the last time the job was run.

It does this by reading the user IDs from an Active Directory group and compares them against the IDs it saved in a file the day before.

I first read the AD group into a hashtable ($ADUsersHashtable)
I then read the file into a similar hashtable ($YesterdaysADUsersFile)
Both hashtables use the UserID as the key.
I then check to see if each ID in $ADUsersHashtable is in $YesterdaysADUsersFile. An ID that is in $ADUsersHashtable but not in $YesterdaysADUsersFile is an ID that was added to AD since the last time this job ran.

The problem is, if $YesterdaysADUsersFile has more than one entry in it, the containskey method always returns true (see output below)

If I delete all but one entry in the file, the code works as expected.

If i have more than one entry in the file the code doesn't work as expected.

The following is the code that reads AD and the file into the hashtables and then compares the keys.

```
$scriptName = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
$LogFile = "D:\Polarion\data\logs\User Access Dates\$scriptName.log"
$Today = Get-Date
$outDate = get-date -format "yyyy-MM-dd"
Add-content $LogFile "$Today Running $scriptName"
$MyServer = $env:computername
Add-content $LogFile "`t$Today Running on $MyServer"

#Will be populated with IDs from AD that i didn't find yesterday
$NewUsersFile = "D:\Polarion\data\logs\User Access Dates\NewUsersInPEALM_ALL_USERSADGroup.txt" 
clear-content $NewUsersFile #I only want the new users from todays AD group.

$ADUsersHashtable = @{} #Contains IDs of the members in the AD Group.
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity PEALM_ALL_USERS -Recursive `
    | Get-ADObject -Properties SamAccountName, mail `
    | select SamAccountName, mail `
    | foreach {$ADUsersHashtable.Add($_.SamAccountName, $_.mail)}
#$ADUsersHashtable

$YesterdaysADUsersFile = "D:\Polarion\data\logs\User Access Dates\UserIdFromPEALM_ALL_USERS.txt" #Contains the IDs that I knew about the last time this ran.
$YesterdaysADUsersHashTable = @{}
$YesterdaysADUsersHashTable = Get-Content($YesterdaysADUsersFile) | 
    foreach {$_.ToString().Replace(":", "=")} | 
    ConvertFrom-StringData
$YesterdaysADUsersHashTable

$NoNewUsersFound = $true
foreach ($UserIDFromAD in $ADUsersHashtable.keys){ #For each user ID in Todays AD group
    if ($YesterdaysADUsersHashTable.containsKey($UserIDFromAD)){ #If the UserID is in Yesterdays list ignore it.
        write-host YesterdaysADUsersHashTable contains key $UserIDFromAD
    } else {
        $NoNewUsersFound = $false
        write-host YesterdaysADUsersHashTable Doesnt contains key $UserIDFromAD 
        write-host "`tadding $UserIDFromAD to the $NewUsersFile file."
        Add-content $LogFile "`t$Today Adding $UserIDFromAD to $NewUsersFile file"
        Add-Content $NewUsersFile "$UserIDFromAD : $outDate" #if its not in yesterdays list write it to the new users file.
    }
}
if ($NoNewUsersFound){
    Add-content $LogFile "`t$Today No new users IDs found in Active Directory."
}
#Clear-Content $YesterdaysADUsersFile #we want to overwrite the file, not append to it. 
#$ADUsersHashtable.keys `
#    | %{ Add-Content $YesterdaysADUsersFile "$_ : $($ADUsersHashtable.$_)" } #writes the content of the hashtable to a file.
```

The following is the output when the file (and hence $YesterdaysADUsersHashTable) has two entries in it. 
The first four lines are the dump of $YesterdaysADUsersHashTable.
The next five lines are from the output from the write-host commands in the if-containskey block. They show that hashtable.containskey is returning true for every key in $ADUsersHashtable. But those keys are not in $YesterdaysADUsersHashTable, this is what i don't understand.

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                               
----                           -----                                                                                                                                               
QZMRW2                         xxxx.xxxx@xxxx.com                                                                                                                 
dzrbcn                         xxxx.xxxx@xxxx.com  

YesterdaysADUsersHashTable contains key QZMRW2
YesterdaysADUsersHashTable contains key dzrbcn
YesterdaysADUsersHashTable contains key MZDP2G
YesterdaysADUsersHashTable contains key BZ5LBQ
YesterdaysADUsersHashTable contains key FZ080Y
```

$YesterdaysADUsersHashTable clearly doesn't contain "MZDP2G", "BZ5LBQ", or "FZ080Y"

And, if I remove everything from the file except one user ID, the code seems to work.
$YesterdaysADUsersHashTable now has only one entry "QZMRW2" and the code seems to work.

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                               
----                           -----                                                                                                                                               
QZMRW2                         xxxx.xxxx@xxxx.com  

YesterdaysADUsersHashTable contains key QZMRW2
YesterdaysADUsersHashTable Doesnt contains key dzrbcn
    adding dzrbcn to the D:\Polarion\data\logs\User Access Dates\NewUsersInPEALM_ALL_USERSADGroup.txt file.
YesterdaysADUsersHashTable Doesnt contains key MZDP2G
    adding MZDP2G to the D:\Polarion\data\logs\User Access Dates\NewUsersInPEALM_ALL_USERSADGroup.txt file.
YesterdaysADUsersHashTable Doesnt contains key BZ5LBQ
    adding BZ5LBQ to the D:\Polarion\data\logs\User Access Dates\NewUsersInPEALM_ALL_USERSADGroup.txt file.
YesterdaysADUsersHashTable Doesnt contains key FZ080Y
```

I am clearly not understanding somehting.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just because a _key_ exists doesn't mean that the value it's referencing is not `$null` :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen possibly solved it - reproducing the error: `$hash = @{MyKey = $null}; $hash.MyKey; $hash.MyKey.GetType()`. Because the hashtable looks up the key, but returns the value, and `$UserIDsFromPEALM_ALL_USERSFileHashTable.$key.GetType()` tries to get the type of the value. I am not sure if it is even possible to get the type of the key like that.

Comment: If you want the type of the key inside the loop, just do `$key.GetType()` :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen OK, but I mean with my example, when there is no loop.

Comment: Well, there can be multiple keys - if you just want the first one: `$hash.Keys[0].GetType()`

Comment: @SteveGray Show us how you created/populated the hashtables if you want better qualified answers :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes, by position you can do that, but it was meant to be done by name - however, I think that my question might be invalid, as if I know the key, I should know its type.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó The problem here is that a hashtable will take _any_ type of object as its key, not just strings, so "by name" doesn't necessarily make sense :)

Comment: Variable `$PEALM_ALL_USERSGroupMembersHashTable` you are using in the foreach loop has never been defined. Where does that hashtable come from? P.S. If I may be so bold.. Why are you using such incredibly hard to read variable names? The code could be so much easier to read and find mistakes if yoy name your variables short and to the point.

Comment: @Theo, i changed some of the var names to make it more readable and included all the code.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Just because an object is not a `String`, it does have a kind of name: `$innerhash1 = @{Key1 = "innerhash1"}; $innerhash2 = @{Key2 = "innerhash2"}; $outerhash = @{$innerhash1 = "outerhash1"}; $outerhash += @{$innerhash2 = "outerhash2"}; $outerhash`. But  I don't know how to access however those names like `$outerhash.Key1; $outerhash.{Key1}; $outerhash.@{Key1}; $outerhash.@{Key1 = "innerhash1"}; $outerhash.{Key1 = "innerhash1"}` - none of these work, but it does: `$outerhash.$innerhash1`. So the variable name has the name somehow wrapped, because it is not a positional lookup.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen "Well, there can be multiple keys - if you just want the first one: $hash.Keys[0].GetType()" – this is not correct: `$hash = @{MyKey = $null}; $hash += @{MyOtherKey = "NotNull"}; $hash; $hash.Keys[0]`.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó Not sure what your point is with the last comment? Hashtables don't maintain key order. Wrt to referencing "by name", it's still not a thing if you use non-strings as keys: `$obj1 = [object]::new();$obj2 = [object]::new();$hash = @{ $obj1 = 1; $obj2 = 2}` - there's no "name" corresponding to the identity of the keys in this case. But `$hash[$obj1]` or `$hash[$hash.Keys[0]]` still work, as expected :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The acutal soultion to my question is that hashtables work with a unique hashcode as a key, and that is being looked up. When I try `$outerhash[@{Key1 = "innerhash1"}]`, it is syntactically correct and runs but does not return anything. Now what is inside the brackets might be called looking up by name, because it is a kind of pattern that does exist inside `$outerhash`, but it is not a string. However it does not match, because it is a separate object created each time it is encountered in the code, and has different hashcode each time: `@{Key1 = "innerhash1"}.GetHashCode()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just because a key *exists* doesn't mean that the corresponding value is not `$null`.

See below for an example:

```
$a = @{ keyName = "Value" }
$b = @{ keyName = $null }

foreach($key in $a.Keys){
    if($b.ContainsKey($key)){
        $bValue = $b[$key] # or `$b.$key` if the key is a string

        if($null -eq $bValue){
            Write-Host "Key '$key' exists in '`$b', but its value is `$null :("
        }
    }
}
```

Without details about how you populate your hashtables it's hard to say *why* :)

Comment: @SteveGray Please [edit your existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60548683/edit), comments are not well suited for code :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the code to work by changing from hashtable.containskey to -contains. In the following code snippit, i commented our the line containing .containsKey($UserIDFromAD) and added the line containing $UserIDsFromFile.keys -contains $UserIDFromAD. The code now works as expected.

This has to be something to do with the difference between checking by reference and checkig by value. I know how this works in Java but not in Powershell.

```
#if ($UserIDsFromFile.containsKey($UserIDFromAD)){ #If the UserID is in Yesterdays list ignore it.
if ($UserIDsFromFile.keys -contains $UserIDFromAD){ #If the UserID is in Yesterdays list ignore it.
```

Comment: Could you tell which version of PowerShell & .NET are you using? I could not reproduce it with this: `$innerhash1 = @{Key1 = "innerhash1"}; $innerhash2 = @{Key2 = "innerhash2"}; $outerhash = @{$innerhash1 = "outerhash1"}; $outerhash += @{$innerhash2 = "outerhash2"}; $outerhash` - after this if I query like `$outerhash.$innerhash1; $outerhash.Contains($innerhash1); $outerhash.ContainsKey($innerhash1); $outerhash.Keys -contains $innerhash1`, all of these are giving correct results. Could you test it? Are your results the same (`outerhash1 True True True`)?

Comment: I found the following article that explains what is going on. [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/mshobject-and-methods-that-take-object/)

Comment: Thanks, but with .NET 4.7.2 & PowerShell 5.1 it is not the case: I got `True` for `$hash.ContainsKey($key)`.